# java.io.IOException: Can't process class [class path] (Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10))

Tags: java, proguard

I'm unable to compile java code that my coworker can successfully compile.

I have JRE 8u221.

Proguard is version 6.03

From my build.bat output:

dist-obfuscate:
     [echo] Extracting Objfuscator
    [unzip] Expanding: c:\Workspaces\abcd\efg\Trunk\ESDE\Scripts\proguard\proguard6.0.3.zip into c:\Workspaces\abcd\efg\Trunk\ESDE\Scripts\proguard
     [echo] Jarring Base ESDE
     [copy] Copying 1 file to c:\Workspaces\abcd\efg\Trunk\ESDE\Scripts\proguard

```
 [java] ProGuard, version 6.0.3java.io.IOException: Can't read [c:\Workspaces\abcd\efg\Trunk\ESDE\Scripts\proguard\sdeIn.jar] (Can't process class [company/application/actions/AboutAction.class] (Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10)))

 [java]
 [java] Reading input...
 [java]     at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:214)Reading program jar [c:\Workspaces\abcd\efg\Trunk\ESDE\Scripts\proguard\sdeIn.jar]
 [java]
 [java]     at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
 [java]     at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:162)
 [java]     at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:90)
 [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:255)
 [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:96)
 [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:572)
 [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [company/application/actions/AboutAction.class] (Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10))
 [java]     at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:114)
 [java]     at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
 [java]     at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
 [java]     at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:83)
 [java]     at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
 [java]     at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
 [java]     at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:210)
 [java]     ... 6 more
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10)
 [java]     at proguard.classfile.util.ClassUtil.checkVersionNumbers(ClassUtil.java:148)
 [java]     at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitProgramClass(ProgramClassReader.java:101)
 [java]     at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:430)
 [java]     at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:91)
 [java]     ... 12 more
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

BUILD FAILED
c:\Workspaces\abcd\efg\Trunk\ESDE\build.xml:877: Warning: Could not find file c:\Workspaces\abcd\efg\Trunk\ESDE\Scripts\proguard\sde.jar to copy.

Questions:

1) "Version 55.0"?  Version of...what?

Proguard version = 6.0.3.

2) "Java 10"?  Nope.

java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

This is Java *8*, not 10.

Comment: FWIW 55.0 is the class file version for Java 11. So it seems that somewhere `javac` from JDK11 is being picked up (maybe check `javac -version` output).

Comment: I had similar issue and I have answered for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74928391/20446879)

Answer (score 1):

The `company.application.actions.AboutAction` class has been compiled for Java 11.

ProGuard 6.0 only supports Java 10.

You need ProGuard 6.1 for Java 11 support.

See [Version history](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/versions) in the [ProGuard Manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual):

> #### Version 6.1 (May 2019)
>
> - ...
> - [PGD-188] Added support for Java 10, 11, and 12.
> - ...
>
> #### Version 6.0 (Feb 2018)
>
> - ...
> - [PGD-186] Added support for Java 10.
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Update gradle version work for me
```

I have updated gradle version and gradle wrapper version and its work for me

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'  

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to perform an upgrade of Android Studio and my Java version, in addition to the Android Gradle plugin, as I began encountering issues with Android Studio after updating the Gradle plugin to 7+. These are the configured versions that made the 'Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10)' error disappear:

Previous:

- Android Studio 4.1
- Java 8
- Gradle 4.6
- Android Gradle Plugin 2.3.3

New:

- Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1
- Java 11
- Gradle 7.4
- Android Gradle Plugin 7.3