# android.car package is unavailable in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-automotive

Unable to access to **android.car** package.

After adding `useLibrary 'android.car'` to build.gradle of app module it started building and running on emulator, but Android Studio still unable to access and/or show them.

```
import android.car.Car
import android.car.VehiclePropertyIds
import android.car.hardware.CarPropertyValue
import android.car.hardware.property.CarPropertyManager
```

Android Studio versions:

1. **Chipmunk 2021.2.1 | Patch 1**
2. **Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 2**

Android SDK: 29, 30, 31, 32

How can I fix it. Or somehow add android.car.jars. Because it is impossible to normally develop without highlighting and importing packages.

Comment: For now, I just add from sdk/platforms/android-32/optional/android.car.jar to app/libs folder of the project. 32 is my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion version. And seems it is correctly show now. But I really dont like that solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

[Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234749386):

> Thank you for your patience while our engineering team worked to
> resolve this issue. A fix for this issue is now available in:
>
> Android Studio Giraffe Canary 1 (2022.3.1.1)
> Android Gradle Plugin 8.1.0
> We encourage you to try the latest update.
>
> If you notice further issues or have questions, please file a new bug
> report.

---

**Old answer:**

The issue is still there in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234749386)

**OPTION 1:**

1- Copy `sdkDir/platforms/android-XX/optional/android.car.jar` to `yourProjectDir/app/libs/android.car.jar`

I tested with `android-32`

2- Add it to the dependencies section in your `build.gradle`

```
compileOnly files("libs/android.car.jar")
```

**OPTION 2:**

Based on @werner's answer for groovy `build.gradle`

```
    def sdkDir = project.android.sdkDirectory.canonicalPath
    def androidCarJar = "$sdkDir/platforms/android-32/optional/android.car.jar"
    implementation(files(androidCarJar))
```

---

Tested on:

Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 8

Comment: Test on Flamingo as well, and according to issue tracker it should be fixed in next Android Studio version.

Answer (score 4):

In my project I have a similar problem, when I have upgraded target sdk version from 32 to 33.  It occurs when pro-guard is enabled. I have tried many solutions. But the solution which worked for me is,

To move **android.car.jar** package path from `/Users/$username/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/optional` to `/Users/$username/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33`.

Hope it will helps you too.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer to the question (can't comment yet):

in our project we have a similar problem. Chipmunk does not detect and/or resolve our project's custom SDK add-on. It worked with BumbleBee.

We added dependencies to include the JAR files of the custom add-on, like this:

```
// See comment in the dependencies section below
val sdkDir: String = project.android.sdkDirectory.canonicalPath
val addOnPath = "$sdkDir/add-ons/addon-project-add-on/libs"

...
    // FIXME: Currently AS Chipmunk seems to have an issue to resolve custom SDK add-on
    //        jars. Gradle works and builds, only the IDE part seems to have a problem.
    //        The next line explicitly adds the custom SDK add-on JAR files as dependencies
    //        and AS Chipmunk's IDE part can now resolve classes etc.
    //        This is a workaround and maybe even a dirty trick and should be removed once
    //        AS was fixed. Need to check if this also works with CI (zuul)
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to addOnPath, "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
```

In this regard Chipmunk is broken IMHO.

We also use Android-car and use this:

```
val androidCarJar = "$sdkDir/platforms/android-30/optional/android.car.jar"

...
implementation(files(androidCarJar))
```

We do not copy the JAR, just reference it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Car APIs (android.car.Car) support in Android Studio

```
Note: You need to have AOSP code to achieve this solution
```

Step1. Go to your AOSP code base and run below mentioned commands

```
AOSP$ source build/envsetup.sh

AOSP$ lunch aosp_car_x86-userdebug

AOSP$ cd packages/services/Car/car-lib
AOSP$ mm
```

Once car-lib module is built successfully, Go to below mentioned path and copy classes.jar file

```
AOSP$ cd out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.car_intermediates/
```

Copy that classes.jar file and paste in your projects libs folder (e.g. MyApp/app/libs)

right click on the classes.jar file in libs and select Add as Library option

OR

you can directly add implementation files('libs/classes.jar') in your dependencies in build.gradle (app) file