# How to read handbrake and PropertyIds from Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api, android-auto, android-automotive

I have experience with Android automotive and i was able to receive PropertyIds like handbrake, rpm and other stuff perfectly.

Now i want to do the same with Android Auto only, i know it's possible because Waze do it perfectly, it detects the state of the handbrake, now the question is how ?

I mean what feature should i check for running PropertyManager and Car library properly ?

Here is an example of code that works on Automotive but not on Android Auto :

```java
car = Car.createCar(context);
```

it crash on Android Auto :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/car/Car;

    at com.tib.androidautotest.CarPropertyHelper.startCan(CarPropertyHelper.java:37)

    at com.tib.androidautotest.CarPropertyService.onCreate(CarPropertyService.java:39)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4379)
```

I think that's normal cause Android Auto does not have car library (i guess), but what should i do for accessing PropertyIds ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [`android.car`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/package-summary) library is only available on Android Automotive OS (see [Can't use Android Auto 'android.car' library - throws RuntimeException: Stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454276/cant-use-android-auto-android-car-library-throws-runtimeexception-stub)). For Android Auto, the only way to read car hardware information/state is via the `CarHardwareManager`'s `CarInfo` and `CarSensors` classes (https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#car-hardware). As such, there isn't currently a way to get handbrake state or RPM info on Android Auto (at least not without requiring the user to have a paired OBD II reader and communicating with that directly).